# Is nfcp equivalent to stable + eliminates $\exists^\infty$?

Tags: reference-request, model-theory

Let $T$ be a complete first-order theory. Recall that a formula $\phi(\overline{x},\overline{y})$ has the *finite cover property* (fcp) if for all $n$, there exist $\overline{a}_1,\dots,\overline{a}_n$ such that $$T\models \lnot\exists \overline{x} \bigwedge_{i = 1}^n \phi(\overline{x},\overline{a}_i),$$
but for all $1\leq j \leq n$, $$T\models \exists \overline{x} \bigwedge_{i \neq j} \phi(\overline{x},\overline{a}_i).$$

As usual, a theory has nfcp if no formula has fcp. This condition was introduced by Keisler (in the context of Keisler's order) and studied by Shelah in *Classification Theory*, where it is shown that nfcp implies stability.

It is also easy to see that if $T$ has nfcp, then $T$ eliminates the quantifer $\exists^\infty$ (there exist infinitely many). That is, for every formula $\phi(\overline{x},\overline{y})$, there is a natural number $n$ such that for all $\overline{a}$, if $|\phi(M,\overline{a})|>n$, then $|\phi(M,\overline{a})|$ is infinite.

Now I have heard that there is a converse to these two facts. In particular, a partial converse (with the additional assumption of elimination of imaginaries) is stated as Theorem 2.8 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1312.0586v1.pdf), without proof or a reference:

**Theorem:** If $T=T^{eq}$ is stable and eliminates $\exists^\infty$, then $T$ has nfcp.

Can anyone provide a proof or a reference? The issue doesn't appear to be addressed in *Classification Theory*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, this theorem is from Classification Theory: see Theorem 4.4 there (the "f.c.p. theorem").

Assertion (8) exactly says that $T^{eq}$ does not eliminate $\exists^{\infty}$ and the theorem says that for stable $T$, this is equivalent to having the f.c.p.

Comment: Wow, somehow I missed this. Thanks, Pierre.

Comment: BTW (for other people happening upon this), the fcp theorem is 4.4 of Chapter II.